# componentWillUpdate -- is it safe to modify nextProps or nextState?

Tags: reactjs

What are the implications of doing this?

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        nextState.bar = transformSomehow(nextState.foo);
    }
}
```

My gut tells me that this is wrong, but I haven't found any documentation saying that `nextProps` and `nextState` should be read-only, nor have I found anything saying that this is ok.

The idea here is that I want some kind of sanitized/transformed/modified version of data from state.  There are probably plenty of other (better) ways to do this, but is this also a viable option?

Comment: Props should be treated as read-only: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only

Comment: Actually I have verified that `nextProps` is indeed unmodifiable. Some getter/setter magics. For `nextState` I couldn't say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that this is not an ideal approach because you are trying to mutate state.  You should not call `setState` from within `componentWillUpdate`, nor should you try to update your state object at this point.  This stage is used more for animations, DOM manipulations, etc.

If you want to set some other vars based on nextState, go for it.  If you want to work ad hoc copies of state to get something done, all good.  But I think that attempting to mutate state in this method runs counter to the intended use of this lifecycle method.  From the docs on `componentWillUpdate`:

> Note that you cannot call this.setState() here. If you need to update state in response to a prop change, use componentWillReceiveProps() instead.

Comment: Agreed -- even though it doesn't seem to warn or break when this is done, it definitely looks like a code smell and shouldn't be done.